# Button with "link" to a class in a different package

Tags: class, button, package

In MainActivity.java I created a button b3 and I want the "link" to be Atwivity_SMS_here.class but this class is in another package and when I launch the app and click on the button it says that the application has stopped unexpectedly so I guess it can't "see" the class

How can I "show" in which package is this class?

Thanks in advance

Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_SMS_here.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```